# How to insert data into table varaible by checking boolean flag

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-insert, where-clause

In My stored procedure have a table variable called, `@detaiResultTable` and, This is my part of stored procedure and how I inserting data into that table variable.

```
INSERT INTO @detaiResultTable 
SELECT b.branchid, 
       sp.fkserviceid, 
       Count(sp.fkserviceid) AS ServiceCount 
FROM   lobby l 
       INNER JOIN @Branches br 
               ON l.fkbranchid = br.branchid 
WHERE  l.addedlocaltime >= @startDate 
and sp.ServiceTime is not null
GROUP  BY b.branchid, 
          sp.fkserviceid
```

Newly I introduced another bit parameter to my SP called `isCheked`. Now I need to check `sp.ServiceTime is not null` condition when `isCheked` parameter is **1** and other if it is **0**, I need to exclude this condition `sp.ServiceTime is not null`.

I just tried this

```
IF @isCheked = 1
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @detaiResultTable 
    .
    .
    WHERE  l.addedlocaltime >= @startDate
    and sp.ServiceTime is not null
    GROUP  BY b.branchid, sp.fkserviceid 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @detaiResultTable 
    .
    .
    WHERE  l.addedlocaltime >= @startDate
    GROUP  BY b.branchid, sp.fkserviceid 
END
```

I need to know, Can i do this without using SQL IF statement. because In my SP have multiple Table variables, So If I used `IF statement`, My SP will be getting a huge code.

Answer (score 0):

Use boolean logic:

```
INSERT INTO @detaiResultTable
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE 
    l.addedlocaltime >= @startDate 
    AND (sp.ServiceTime IS NOT NULL OR @isCheked = 0)
GROUP BY ...
```

Comment: it bit confusing to me, what will happen when, `@isCheked = 1`. If it is 1, you mean this will not be executed  `sp.ServiceTime IS NOT NULL` ? I'm I correct, can u please explain,  bit confusing to me.

Comment: @thomsan: if `@ischecked = 1`, then condition `sp.ServiceTime IS NOT NULL` must be fullfilled, otherwise the row is filtered out.